# CString to COleVariant causing random crash

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring

I have a MFC application where I have derived a class from `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` to call a dialog box when a custom drawn button is clicked in property window. In the `OnButtonClick()` function I have to set the output to `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` member variable `m_varValue` which is of type `COleVariant`. To put the `CString` type output of the dialog(`sDlgOutputString`) in `m_varValue` I am using `->`

```
m_varValue = COleVariant(sDlgOutputString);
```

This line is working fine in my machine but in some machine this line is causing crash sometimes. I have checked with temporarily commenting the code and saw it is not crashing without it but not updating also. What am I doing wrong with the conversion from `CString` to `COleVariant`? What should be the proper procedure ?

Comment: How do you know this is the line that crashes your application? Did you do any remote debugging? What is `m_varValue`?

Comment: Directly or indirectly that line iscausing the crash. I have compiled the program only commenting that line, and it never crashed after that. But that was a temporary solution.

m_varValue is a meber variable of CMFCPropertyGridProperty which determines what will be shown in the propertygrid. [Here is a link](https://pvpgn-magic-builder.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/module/include/vsexpress_include/afxpropertygridctrl.h)

Comment: I don't think you should set that directly, but use `SetValue()` instead.

Comment: What kind of crash. Heap fault or defect? What does the stack trace says. I don't think that this line alone could cause a crash. It is absolutely valid and it is something I do al the time.